# grouping by number sequences in r

Tags: r

say I have the `iris` dataset.

`data(iris)`

There are 150 rows in the dataset.

How can I `group_by` the first 50 rows and then `group_by` rows 51:100, and then finally `group_by` 101:150?

Some python code that I am following is using (nothing to do with the iris data):

```
data.reset_index().assign(groupId = lambda row: row.index // 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On option would be `gl` (or another is `rep`)

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
   group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 50, n()))) %>%
   summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#    grp Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#  <int>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     1         5.01        3.43         1.46       0.246
#2     2         5.94        2.77         4.26       1.33 
#3     3         6.59        2.97         5.55       2.03
```

---

Or another option is `%/%`

```
(seq_len(nrow(iris))-1) %/% 50 + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(iris)[, .( mean( Sepal.Length ) ), by = .( rleid( 0:(nrow( iris ) - 1) %/% 50) )][]
```

`rleid()` is used to create groups to summarise by (in this case, the mean of `Sepal.Length` (by group of 50 rows) is calculated into column `V1`.

```
   rleid    V1
1:     1 5.006
2:     2 5.936
3:     3 6.588
```